# Errno::ENOENT error in Ruby Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed the jquery ruby gems.

From then on I am getting this error Errno::ENOENT
No such file or directory - Asset file not found at '/public/javascripts/jquery-ui.js'

Please help me with this error.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the generator? `rails g jquery:install --ui` - the gem should be `jquery-rails`